# Match SteamID with ban duration from listid result

Tags: php, regex, parsing, steam

I use a php library to execute commands on a srcds-server via rcon. In this case I want to get all bans and their durations. When I execute `listid` via rcon, I get, after some parsing, for example this text:

```
1 STEAM_1:0:12345678 : permanent 2 STEAM_1:0:87654321 : 30.000 min
```

Now I want to get an array which contains the SteamID and the duration per set, like this:

```
$Bans = [
   "STEAM_1:0:12345678" => "permanent",
   "STEAM_1:0:87654321" => "30.000 min",
]
```

Since I can't use `explode` in a good way to do this for me (or at least I don't know how I should do that), I want to try it with regex. My attempt so far:

```
/^(?:\d\s)(STEAM_[0-5]:[01]:[0-9]{1,8})(?:\s:\s)(permanent|\d{1,}\.000\smin)/g
```

But that doesn't match it in the right way. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right regex with preg_match_all is:

```
preg_match_all("/(?:\d\s)(STEAM_[0-5]:[01]:[0-9]{1,8})(?:\s:\s)(permanent|\d{1,}\.000\smin)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

I needed to remove the `^`. Now, I don't even have to do all the exploding beforehand. I matches the right parts even from the raw result:

```
ID filter list: 2 entries 1 STEAM_1:0:12345678 : permanent 2 STEAM_1:0:87654321 : 30.000 min L 05/20/2015 - 15:48:53: rcon from "188.40.142.20:60799": command "listid"
```